# Permission, что текущий юзер может запрашивать информацию только о себе Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Каким образом реализовать ограничение, что текущий юзер может запрашивать информацию только о себе? Например uuid текущего авторизованного пользователя `69909317-bd29-47b8-8878-5884182e4948` и при вызове метода user/69909317-bd29-47b8-8878-5884182e4948 возвращалась информаци по этому юзеру, а если , например `user/11111111-bd29-47b8-8878-5884182e4948` ( uuid другого юзера) бросалось исключение. Я пытался пробывать

```
class IsOwner(permissions.BasePermission):

def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
    return obj.owner == request.user
```

Но ловлю ошибку - у obj нет атрибута owner

Comment: добавь описание моделей, которые ты используешь и для которых ты хочешь получить такую проверку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас класс IsOwner должен вернуть True или False

Вот пример проверки, является ли пользователь superuser

```
class IsAdmin(permissions.BasePermission):
    
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.user.is_superuser == True
            return True
        else:
            return False
```